# HTML and CSS - banner and background positioning

Tags: html, css

I am building a simple landing page where the visitor would see a banner, a background image below it and a couple of buttons located vertically beneath each other.

The problem I am experiencing is that, at the moment, both the banner and the background image are starting from the same position (the top left corner of the web page), thus part of the background is hidden by the banner.

The code I currently have is:

```
<style>
  body {
    background: url("http://url.to/background") no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }

  #Wrap {
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="Wrap">
    <img src="http://url.to/banner" />
  </div>
</body>
```

The expected result is to have the banner image take the beginning of the page while fitting into the screen without causing any extra scroll to appear. What is more important is to have the background start after the banner.

A fiddle could be found at the following URL:

https://jsfiddle.net/morL1zka/

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can You create one fiddle for this?

Comment: @fruitjs Perhaps you mean a screenshot? Please excuse me ignorance.

Comment: take a look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and you will see what fruitjs is asking for.. ;)

Comment: Thank you, I added a link to a fiddle.

Comment: Hi metaarch, Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

you should use     `background-position-y` for this, and you need to set value which is equal to the height of the banner

```css
body {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px; 
  background-position-y: 100px;/*the value must be the same height as the banner */
  
}

#Wrap {

  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrap">
  <img src="http://url.to/banner" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easyli solve this using JavaScript. The Backgroundposition will be automatically set under the banner, without knowing the height of it.

```js
var body = document.getElementById('body-margin');
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');

body.style.backgroundPositionY = banner.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

```css
body {
  background: url("http://simonakoleva.me/wp-content/themes/hitchcock/images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#Wrap {
  background-color: #345370;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body id="body-margin">
  <div id="Wrap">
    <img id="banner" src="http://simonakoleva.me/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/mybanner.jpg" />
  </div>
</body>
```

> Here is also your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/morL1zka/2/

Comment: I did try adding <main>, but it looks like this is messing up the margin of the banner, positioning it a couple of pixels below the beginning of the page.

Comment: @metaarch please check my edited answer. i've got an other solution for you. ive also added an backgroundcolor to #wrap, to provide a nice look on each windowsize.